# time management for applications: apply more or apply better?

Tags: job-search, faculty-application, time-management

I am a postdoc applying for tenure-track assistant professorship positions. I am writing one application per day and have less time that positions to apply for: some job offers expire before I am able to submit. Recently, the templates of my application files (cv, research statement, teaching statement, cover letter) have been proof-read by a native English speaker, and some blatantly embarrassing errors have been found and corrected.

It would take me 1-2 full days to correct about 7 applications which have already been uploaded to the human-resources sites of various institutions but which are still editable. What's better: invest time into one or two new applications or correct errors in the old ones?

Comment: I would recommend to focus on the positions you would like to obtain, or that you think you are likely to get: don't waste time fixing an application where you suspect you have few chances, or for a job you are unlikely to accept. But I suspect the answer you'll get will be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: It would take you up to 2 days to correct errors in 7 applications? That seems like a very long time for that.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It is not only "correcting errors", it's also finding out which applications are *actually* still editable, indeed logging in, replacing files, dealing with "Error 403 - system maintenance", and all the usual dirty electronic fuss. Correction itself is an hour per application, assuming the documents are found and already open in the corresponding editor.